# resolving integral using gamma function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

My book solves this integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} y^3e^{-ay} dy
\end{equation}
using gamma function as
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a^4}\Gamma(4)
\end{equation}
why is this true?

Comment: i know that this mathjax is completely wrong with this.
is an integral defined from 0 to infinite of y^3 multiplied for e^(-ay)
the result is 1/a^4 multiplied for gamma(4)

Comment: integration by parts, differentiate $y^3$ and integrate $e^{-ay}$. then repeat and repeat.... you should notice every time the thing you need to evaluate = 0. please have a go, using my suggestion and edit the question or post it as an answer. As it stands this question does not meet the standard of the quality of question expected on this site.

Comment: also note $\Gamma(4) = 3! = 6$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The change of variable $t=ay$ is useful.

**Edit**

We have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} y^3e^{-ay} dy=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac t a\right)^3e^{-t}\frac{dt}{a}=\frac 1 {a^4}\int_0^\infty t^3e^{-t}dt=\frac{\Gamma(4)}{a^4}
\end{equation}

Comment: i do not see why integrating $e^{-t}t^3$ is any easier than the problem in question.

Comment: @Lost1 You can use the Gamma function now

Comment: You are right, given the fact the question used $\Gamma(4)$ rather than 6...

Comment: @Lost1 I edited my answer.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Nice and enough edit. :+)

Answer (score 2):

Besides to Sami's post , note that: $$\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}x^n\exp(-x)dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^Mx^n\exp(-x)dx=\cdots=n\Gamma(n),~~n>0$$

Comment: this needs a TU +1